# Why App Open Ads runs before MainActivity?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm asking why after I placed the App Open Ads in the **AppOpenManager** and some other code added on **MyApplication** same article that Google Admob advices to use but I'm still confused, Why when I launch my app:

The **Splash screen** : Open First
Then the **App Open Ad**s opens and stay running in the background while the **MainActivity** opens above the App Open Ads.

If you know how to solve this help me please...

Thanks in advance.

[Here is the GIF about the app I was using for the test to show you App Open Ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN5IW.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

gradle:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def lifecycle_version1 = "2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version1"
```

Manifests

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

AppOpenManager.java

```
        import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Application;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    
    import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;
    import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
    import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;
    
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdError;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.appopen.AppOpenAd;
    
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import static androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.Event.ON_START;

public class AppOpenManager  implements LifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks  {
    private long loadTime = 0;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
    private static String AD_UNIT_ID = "abc";
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
    private Activity currentActivity;
    private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;
    private static boolean isShowingAd = false;
    private final MyApplication myApplication;

    /** Constructor */
    public AppOpenManager(MyApplication myApplication) {
        this.myApplication = myApplication;
        this.AD_UNIT_ID = myApplication.getString(R.string.app_open_id);
        this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }


    /** LifecycleObserver methods */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
    public void onStart() {
        showAdIfAvailable();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
    }
    /** Request an ad */
    public void fetchAd() {
        // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
        if (isAdAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        loadCallback =
                new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
                     *
                     * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                        AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = ad;
                        AppOpenManager.this.loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                    }

                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
                     *
                     * @param loadAdError the error.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }

                };
        AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
        AppOpenAd.load(
                myApplication, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
                AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);
    }

    /** Creates and returns ad request. */
    private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    }

    /** Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
        long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - this.loadTime;
        long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
        return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
    }
    /** Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown. */
    public boolean isAdAvailable() {
        return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
    }

    /** ActivityLifecycleCallback methods */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = null;
    }

    /** Shows the ad if one isn't already showing. */
    public void showAdIfAvailable() {
        // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
        // and an ad is available.
        if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

            FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                    new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                            isShowingAd = false;
                            fetchAd();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            isShowingAd = true;
                        }
                    };

            appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);

        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
            fetchAd();
        }
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

/** The Application class that manages AppOpenManager. */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static AppOpenManager appOpenManager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MobileAds.initialize(
                this,
                new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
                });

        appOpenManager = new AppOpenManager(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Google have mentioned in "**Cold starts and loading screens**" Section [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open), app open ads will show when users foreground the app when it's suspended in memory. "Cold starts" occur when the app is launched but was not previously suspended in memory.

What we should do is avoid using `System.exit(0)` in `onBackPressed()` for exiting the app since it will  make the app in `Cold starts` mode when opened. Just use `finishAffinity()` for exiting the app.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
 @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
public void onStart() {
showAdIfAvailable();
            
}
```

with this

```
 @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
public void onStart() {
            if (!(currentActivity instanceof SplashActivity)) {
                showAdIfAvailable();
            }
}
```